# Burning arduino generate hex file to blank atmel chip

Tags: avr

Is it possible to burn the hex file to a blank chip, generated by Arduino to burn using USBASP to that particular chip without using Arduino board ? Will the program work ?

---

My main goal is to use Atmega328P for low power. Should I select Arduino pro mini in the arduino IDE ?

Ater successful testing I will just burn the hex file to another 50 chips. thats why I dont want to use arduino board.

Comment: Can you please reword your question to be a little more clear?

Comment: I wan to burn the hex file which is generated by arduino ide. But dont want to use arduino board. Instead I want to burn by USBASP like regular avr program hex file burning.

Comment: Note that the Arduino IDE supports several programmers directly, including the USBasp.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The binary generated by the Arduino IDE in no way requires the presence of the Arduino bootloader in order to operate. Note that certain characteristics such as the MCU and clock rate are set at build time and cannot be changed in the final binary.

Comment: Do I have to do anything with fuse settings while burning ?

Comment: The clock settings should match those expected by the code. The other fuses are up to whatever is required for the application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's no problem as long as you check your fuse bytes. And the connections to the 6pin ISP header.
Make sure you study the avrdude command line and the manual for the particular Atmel chip.

I'm assuming the programmer you are using must use avrdude to be able to work.

I often use a nice GUI called "avrdudess" which is freeware. Great for avr beginners, and takes some of the effort out of writing directly into the command prompt.

Comment: I will check avrdudess

Comment: What will be the fuse settings if I use Arduino UNO as platform in IDE ?